# Effective boundary and Pareto optimal solution. Multi-Objective oprimization

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I am starting to learn Control Theory, and start to explore Multi-objective optimization, I cant find in the net examples of how to solve such tasks, may someone advice how to solve this kind of problems, example:
$$f_1(x, y) = 1 + x \to max, (x \ge 0, y \ge , x + y \le 1)$$
$$f_2(x, y) = 1 - y \to max, (x \ge 0, y \ge , x + y \le 1)$$
I need to find **effective boundary** and **Pareto optimal solution**.
I tried to find methods to solve this problem, but I couldn't find any example... Any help?